# Arangodb freeze when page fault increased

Tags: arangodb

I using arango with nodejs and arangojs driver, one of the arango collection has 10,000,000 documents
Sometimes page fault going up (150 or 500) and arango freezed and don't response to query request Also freezed arango web panel.

My server config is:
RAM: 6 GB
CPU: 8 core
(From web panel arango using 4.76 GB (83.90 %) 6 GB of ram)

**UPDATE1**
This is output of `/_api/collection/AdsStatics/figures`

```
{
  "id": "191689719157",
  "name": "AdsStatics",
  "isSystem": false,
  "doCompact": true,
  "isVolatile": false,
  "journalSize": 33554432,
  "keyOptions": {
    "type": "traditional",
    "allowUserKeys": true
  },
  "waitForSync": false,
  "indexBuckets": 8,
  "count": 7816780,
  "figures": {
    "alive": {
      "count": 7815806,
      "size": 3563838968
    },
    "dead": {
      "count": 306,
      "size": 167464,
      "deletion": 0
    },
    "datafiles": {
      "count": 104,
      "fileSize": 3530743672
    },
    "journals": {
      "count": 1,
      "fileSize": 33554432
    },
    "compactors": {
      "count": 0,
      "fileSize": 0
    },
    "shapefiles": {
      "count": 0,
      "fileSize": 0
    },
    "shapes": {
      "count": 121,
      "size": 56520
    },
    "attributes": {
      "count": 24,
      "size": 56
    },
    "indexes": {
      "count": 3,
      "size": 1660594864
    },
    "lastTick": "10044860034955",
    "uncollectedLogfileEntries": 985,
    "documentReferences": 0,
    "waitingFor": "-",
    "compactionStatus": {
      "message": "checked datafiles, but no compaction opportunity found",
      "time": "2016-02-24T08:29:27Z"
    }
  },
  "status": 3,
  "type": 2,
  "error": false,
  "code": 200
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your system is running out of memory. The datafiles for the one collection are 3,530,743,672 bytes in size, the indexes are 1,660,594,864. That is about 5.1 GB for this one collection alone.

arangod will need further memory for its WAL, the V8 contexts and temporary query results in order to operate properly.

Provided the system has 6 GB of total RAM and the OS and other processes need some RAM, too, it looks like you're running out of memory.
I am wondering if you're seeing some sort of swapping activity, which would explain why (all) operations would get extremely slow.